# Reading xml with java

Tags: java, xml

Hey I'd like to read and write xml code with java so I google'd how to do it but what i found was only engine's who could read real easy xml code such as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

But I'd like to read more advance'd such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package>
    <template name="store_avatars">

        <!-- UI validation for this file -->
        <panel noclick="1" onload="CreateBool('ui_avatars_package_loaded', true);"/>

        <!-- Female Pyromancer -->  
        <instance name="altAvatarPreviewPanel"
            heroEntryID="1"
            id="15"
            product="Hero_Pyromancer.Female"
            definition="/heroes/pyromancer"
            heroName="Hero_Pyromancer"
            hero_icon_path="/heroes/pyromancer/icon.tga"
            hasvoice="true"
            hasmodel="true"
            hastexture="true"
            hassounds="true"
            hasanimations="true"
            haseffects="false"
        />

        <!-- Sexy Moon Queen -->
        <instance name="altAvatarPreviewPanel"
            heroEntryID="2"
            id="16"
            product="Hero_Krixi.Sexy"
            definition="/heroes/krixi"
            heroName="Hero_Krixi"
            hero_icon_path="/heroes/krixi/icons/hero.tga"
            hasvoice="false"
            hasmodel="true"
            hastexture="true"
            hasanimations="true"
            haseffects="false"
        />
    </template>
</package>
```

So I went ahead and did my own classes for this,

```
package Lindholm.languages;

import java.util.Vector;

import Lindholm.LLException;
import Lindholm.LLString;
import Lindholm.com.LLProperty;

public class Xml {
    //STATIC variables;

    //Variables;
    private    Tag tag;
    //Setup;

    //Constructor;
    public Xml(String xml) {
        int index1;

        //First removing all the comments so they dont' disturb the decoding;
        index1 = 0;
        while((index1 = xml.indexOf("<!--",index1)) != -1) {
            int index2;

            if((index2 = xml.indexOf("-->",index1)) != -1) {
                String comment = xml.substring(index1,index2+"-->".length());
                xml = LLString.replace(xml,comment,"",1);
            }
            else {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("Invail xml code, missing \"-->\".");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    new LLException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        //replacing all "/>" cancelings to "</[abc]>";
        index1 = 0;
        while((index1 = xml.indexOf("/>",0)) != -1) {
            int index2;

            String revstr = LLString.reverse(xml.substring(0,index1+"/>".length()));
            index2 = revstr.indexOf("<",0);
            index2 = revstr.length()-index2;
            String name = xml.substring(index2,index1).split("\\s")[0];

            xml = LLString.replace(xml,"/>","></"+name+">",1);
        }

        //Adding index's to all tags which will make the decoding easier.
        index1 = 0;
        int n = 0;
        Vector<Integer> openings = new Vector<Integer>();
        while(true) {
            int index0 = index1;
            int index2;
            n++;

            index1 = xml.indexOf("<",index0);
            index2 = xml.indexOf("</",index0);
            if(index1 != -1) {
                index1 += "<".length();
            }

            if(index1 != -1 && (index1 < index2 || index2 == -1)) {
                xml = xml.substring(0,index1)+n+"-"+xml.substring(index1);
                openings.add(n);
                index1 += (n+"-").length();
            }
            else if(index2 != -1 && (index2 < index1 || index1 == -1)) {
                xml = xml.substring(0,index2+"</".length())+openings.get(openings.size()-1)+"-"+xml.substring(index2+"</".length());
                index1 += (openings.get(openings.size()-1)+"-").length();
                openings.remove(openings.size()-1);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        //Now let's decode it!!!
        xml = xml+"</1-?xml>";
        tag = readTag(xml,"1-?xml");
    }
    //Set;

    //Get;
    public Tag getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    //Add;

    //Remove;

    //Do;

    //Other;
    private Tag readTag(String xmltag,String tagname) {
        int index1 = ("<"+tagname).length(); //subract 1 due the first index is 0!
        int index2;
        String body = xmltag.substring(xmltag.indexOf(">",0)+">".length(),xmltag.indexOf("</"+tagname,0));
        LLProperty properties;
        Vector<Tag> children = new Vector<Tag>();

        index2 = xmltag.indexOf(">",index1);
        String xmlproperties = xmltag.substring(index1,index2);
        properties = readProperties(xmlproperties);

        while((index1 = body.indexOf("<",0)) != -1) {
            index2 = body.indexOf(">",index1);
            String subtagname = body.substring(index1+"<".length(),index2).split("\\s")[0];

            index2 = body.indexOf("</"+subtagname,index1)+"</".length();
            index2 = body.indexOf(">",index2)+">".length();

            String subxmltag = body.substring(index1,index2);
            body = LLString.replace(body,subxmltag,"",1);

            children.add(readTag(subxmltag,subtagname));
        }
        if(children.size() == 0) {
            body = null;
        }
        tagname = tagname.split("-")[1];

        Tag tag = new Tag(tagname,body);
        tag.setProperties(properties);
        tag.setChildren(children);
        return tag;
    }
    private LLProperty readProperties(String xmlproperties) {
        LLProperty properties = new LLProperty();
        int index1 = 0;
        int index2;

        while(xmlproperties.substring(index1).contains("=")) {
            index2 = xmlproperties.indexOf("=",index1);
            String key = LLString.trimAll(xmlproperties.substring(index1,index2));
            key = key.trim();

            index1 = index2+"=".length();
            int squote = xmlproperties.indexOf("'",index1);
            int dquote = xmlproperties.indexOf("\"",index1);
            String quote = "";

            if(squote != -1 && (squote < dquote || dquote == -1)) {
                quote = "'";
            }
            else if(dquote != -1 && (dquote < squote || squote == -1)) {
                quote = "\"";
            }
            else {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("Invail xml code, missing parameters.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    new LLException(e);
                }
            }
            index1 = xmlproperties.indexOf(quote,index1)+quote.length();
            index2 = xmlproperties.indexOf(quote,index1);
            String value = xmlproperties.substring(index1,index2);

            properties.setProperty(key,value);
            index1 = index2+quote.length();
        }

        return properties;
    }
    public void print() {
        String xml = "";
        for(int i = 0;i <= tag.getChildren()-1;i++) {
            xml += printTag(tag.getChild(i),"");
        }
        xml =    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"+
                xml;
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
    private String printTag(Tag tag,String height) {
        String xml =    height+"<"+tag.getTag();

        Object[] keys = tag.getProperties().stringPropertyNames().toArray();
        String prop = " ";
        if(keys.length >= 5) {
            prop = "\n"+height+"    ";
        }

        for(int i = 0;i <= keys.length-1;i++) {
            xml += prop+keys[i]+"=\""+tag.getProperties().getProperty(keys[i].toString())+"\"";
        }
        if(tag.getBody() == null) {
            xml += "/>\n";
        }
        else {
            xml +=    LLString.replace(prop+">\n","    ","",1);
            for(int i = 0;i <= tag.getChildren()-1;i++) {
                xml += printTag(tag.getChild(i),height+"    ");
            }
            xml +=    height+"</"+tag.getTag()+">\n";
        }

        return xml;
    }
    //Implements;

}
```

and tag

```
package Lindholm.languages;

import java.util.Vector;

import Lindholm.com.LLProperty;

public class Tag {
    //STATIC variables;

    //Variables;
    private    String tag;
    private    String body;
    private    LLProperty properties;
    private    Vector<Tag> children = new Vector<Tag>();

    //Setup;

    //Constructor;
    public Tag(String name,String body) {
        tag = name;
        this.body = body;
    }
    //Set;
    public void setProperties(LLProperty properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
    public void setChildren(Vector<Tag> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    //Get;
    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
    public LLProperty getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
    public int getChildren() {
        return children.size();
    }
    public Tag getChild(int index) {
        return children.get(index);
    }
    public Tag getChildByTag(String tagname) {
        for(int i = 0;i <= getChildren()-1;i++) {
            if(getChild(i).getTag().equals(tagname)) {
                return getChild(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Tag getChildByTag(String tagname,int number) {
        for(int i = 0;i <= getChildren()-1;i++) {
            if(getChild(i).getTag().equals(tagname)) {
                if(number == 0) {
                    return getChild(i);
                }
                else {
                    number--;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Add;
    public void addChild(Tag child) {
        children.add(child);
    }

    //Remove;

    //Do;

    //Other;

    //Implements;

}
```

Now my issue is that it's increadably slow, is there any other way to accomplish what i want? or maybe a way to make it faster?, Maybe my code is bad?

Comment: which xml parser are you using to read xml file

Comment: How about looking at JDOM (http://www.jdom.org/) or JAXB (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) ?

Comment: I vote for JAXB. Give it a study and you'll have no regrets!

Comment: What happens when you read the "more advanced" XML? As long as it's well-formed, any conforming parser (including the ones built into the JDK) will be able to read it. I suspect your real problem is that you're producing XML that isn't well-formed. And to avoid that, you should be creating your XML with a serializer, not simply writing strings to a file.

Comment: Here are a couple of articles I wrote on the subject: http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=xml.builder for output, and http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=xml.parsing for parsing.

Comment: oh, you didn't use regex, there's your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. *DON'T*, under any circumstances, try and write your own XML parser. Although on the surface XML looks straightforward, it's actually a very complex standard and you *WILL* miss bits of it. You might just get away with it if you are controlling the XML creation as well. But then if you are, why use XML at all? And if you're not, be prepared for the system/library/vendor that is creating it to suddenly use an advanced feature of XML that your home-built parser doesn't handle.
2. There are plenty of open-source parsers available. There's even one built in to the JDK now. You have the choice of reading the whole document into memory in a DOM structure, or getting an event-stream (SAX). Open source libraries also allow other technologies such as XML Pull.

Look at:

- Xerces: http://xerces.apache.org/ - a version of this is bundled with the JDK
- JDOM: http://www.jdom.org/
- Woodstox: http://woodstox.codehaus.org/
- XMLPull: http://www.xmlpull.org/

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend using the built-in JAXP version of Xerces rather than downloading it explicitly. Also, I believe that XMLPull has become the StAX implementation in JDK 1.6 and above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another XML parser. I heard that [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Reading an XML file in java can be done with quite an ease....

**1.** Use `SAX` Parser

**2.** Use `DOM` Parser

**3.** Use `XML Pull Parsing`